# iniciar servidor com vagrant no windows usando git bash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, windows, vagrant

Como é visto no log abaixo ao iniciar o servidor ocorre tal erro. 
Dei *bundle install* e na sequencia tentei iniciar o servidor.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0
.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/vagrant/local/ruby/gems/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/depend
encies.rb:241:in `load': /vagrant/colchonet/config/routes.rb:63: syntax error, u
nexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema está no arquivo route.rb.

O interpretador do ruby está fazendo a analise do seu código e na linha 63 ele se deparou com um **end** que não deveria estar ali como ele não tem o tratamento para esse comando ele sobe esse erro.

Esse processo é conhecido como Análise Léxica e está presente tanto em interpretadores como em compiladores.